# Error in foreach php

Tags: php, json, foreach

```
function CheckSourceInfoOne($source) {
    foreach ($array as list($a, $b, $c)) {
        list($latitude, $longitude) = explode(',', $c);
        $La = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * from Spotting_TB WHERE latitude = '".$latitude."'");
        $Lo = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * from Spotting_TB WHERE longitude = '".$longitude."'");
        if ($checkLatitude == false && $checkLongitude == false) {
            if ($insert = $dbc->query("INSERT INTO Spotting_TB (spotting_number,P,longitude,latitude,I,time_posted,hidden) VALUES (NULL,'{$b}','{$Lo}','{$La}','0',NOW(),'0')")) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have been trying everything and i cant find out my error in the code :/ Its suposed to take a decoded json and go through it and post it if its not in the database but its not working

Comment: could you post your error message.

Comment: It seems to be a Database error, your foreach syntax seems fine

Comment: Where do you set `$checkLatitude` and `$checkLongitude`?

Comment: @AndreaGhidini Its in the function

Comment: the parameter in the function is called `$source` but you reference `$array` in the loop and the variables `$checkLatitude` and `$checkLongitude` are not defined in the function

Comment: @vijayrana there is no error.

Comment: @RamRaider That was an error but didnt fix it :(

Comment: Error in foreach php? Whats the error?

Comment: You run two queries in that function but you don't use the results correctly - simply using `$La` & `$Lo` will not return the values

Comment: @RamRaider How do i run 2 queries in the same foreach?

Comment: running the queries like that is ok but you need to process the recordsets they both return.

Comment: @RamRaider  so check if the number of rows?

Comment: You also seem to have a scope issue, `$dbc` isn't in this functions scope - pass it as an argument (or a bad idea, make it global)